# Pagination 'previous' link is no working in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

This is my pagination code.When I click 'next' button it displaying the next page with  remaining product images,but if I click 'previous' its showing the empty page.The same code I applied for another page pagination its working fine but its not working for this page.

**Controller**

```
     public function onSectorClick1() {

            $id = $_GET["id"];

            $this->session->set_userdata('subcategory2_id', $_GET['id']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('subcategory2_name', $_GET['name']);
            $this->onSectorClick1Copy();
        }

        public function onSectorClick1Copy() {



            $data['ListMenuLevel1'] = $this->Categories_model->listsector1();

            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() ."index.php/welcome/onSectorClick1Copy";
            $total_row = $this->productdisplay_model->subproductlist_count($this->session->userdata('subcategory2_id'));
            $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
            $config['per_page'] = 20;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config['num_links'] = 1;
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 1);

            $offset = (($config['per_page']) * ($page - 1));
            $limit = $config['per_page'] * $page ;
            $data['sub2products'] = $this->productdisplay_model->sub2Productsmenu($this->session->userdata('subcategory2_id'),$limit, $offset);
            $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
            $this->load->view('subproductlist', $data);
        }
```

**Model**

```
     public function subproductlist_count($id) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('sub2_category');
            $this->db->where('sub1_categoryid_fk', $id);
            $this->db->order_by("sub2_category.sub1_categoryid_fk ");
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return  $query->num_rows();

        }



        public function sub2Productsmenu($id,$limit, $offset){

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('sub2_category');
            $this->db->where('sub1_categoryid_fk', $id);
            $this->db->order_by("sub2_category.sub1_categoryid_fk ");
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            return $this->db->get()->result();


        }
```

**View**

```
     <div class="center">
                <ul class="pagination">
                     <?php
                    foreach ($links as $link) {
                        echo "<li>" . $link . "</li>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: check the url on `previous` link.

Comment: Are you using a framework? `$this->pagination->create_links()` doesn't give enough information as to what is generated. What is rendered in your `pagination` list?

Comment: codeigniter framework I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In my controller code I just changed the session name as sub2_id and I passed the get variable "$id" to the session.The following change in code is displayed below.
```

**Controller**

```
 public function onSectorClick1() {

        $id = $_GET["id"];

        $this->session->set_userdata('sub2_id',  $id);

        $this->onSectorClick1Copy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I create pagination and it works perfectly . Below is code in Controller.

```
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'property/properties';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->property_model->countProperties();
    $config['per_page'] = 6;
    //===========================//
    // Defining Pagination Styles//
    //===========================//
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_link'] = '&lt;&lt;';
    $config['last_link'] = '&gt;&gt;';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['properties']=$this->property_model->getAllProperties($config['per_page'],$offset);
    $data['pagination']=$this->pagination->create_links();
```

and in my view

```
<!-- Start properties content bottom -->
<?php if(isset($pagination)){?>
 <div class="aa-properties-content-bottom">
  <nav>
    <?php echo $pagination?>
  </nav>
 </div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: No error but the code works same as my code.But I am getting error like when I click previous link the page shows empty.

Comment: what url does it creates when you click on previous record?

Comment: first of all remove index.php by htaccess. secondly have you pasted this url in your browser and checked the record appears or not

Comment: Yes I pasted that url and checked records are not showing.

Comment: I removed index.php by htaccess and tried,but its not working.

Comment: means there is a problem with url creation. what is the url when you see the records before moving forward or backwards

Comment: http://localhost/terasukhintrade/index.php/welcome/onSectorClick1?id=3&name=fruits

Comment: This is the url before I moving forward i.e 'next'.

Comment: After I moving from page1 to page 2 the following below given is the url

Comment: http://localhost/terasukhintrade/index.php/welcome/onSectorClick1Copy/2

Comment: I found your problem mate. Use $config["base_url"] = base_url() ."index.php/welcome/onSectorClick1"; instead of the copy function because your default page is rendered by above function , you are just calling the below function to paginate. the below function doesn't have the parameter by which you are getting the record from model

Comment: btw you should do it in a single function instead of splitting it in two

Comment: In first function we are setting id through session

Comment: In second function we are using that session value.

Comment: you are picking up a stone from table, putting it into a sack, then taking it out of the sack and then throwing it into water, why not pick the stone and throw it into water.

Comment: In our application  'onSectorClick1()' function is called we get id once,that id we are putting in session and that session value we using in 'onSectorClick1Copy()' function, Because if we call onsectorClick1() once again we will not get id value.

Comment: then instead of calling that function in click1() write redirect(base_url.'index.php/welcome/onSectorClick1Copy')

Comment: i am passing id in form action ,in form button is clicked once,so i get id once ,if i use redirect(base_url.'index.php/welcome/onSectorClick1Copy') ,i will not get id but  error because form action will not happen second time.So i used two functions to set id and get id from session in other

Comment: thats why i am saying when you have your value in session, redirect to the other function, you get value from session,

Comment: ya right,that what i did in function  onSectorClick1() ,i called another function like this $this->onSectorClick1Copy();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function onSectorClick1($offset=0) {

        $id = $_GET["id"];

        $this->session->set_userdata('subcategory2_id', $_GET['id']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('subcategory2_name', $_GET['name']);

        $data['ListMenuLevel1'] = $this->Categories_model->listsector1();

        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() ."index.php/welcome/onSectorClick1";
        $total_row = $this->productdisplay_model->subproductlist_count($id);
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
        $config['per_page'] = 20;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = 1;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['sub2products'] = $this->productdisplay_model->sub2Productsmenu($id,$limit, $offset);
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
        $this->load->view('subproductlist', $data);
    }
```

There is a working model of this code [here](https://duperty.com/realestate/property/properties)